# Can I use Selenium with password-protected URLs?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to use Selenium for fetching information automatically from an ADSL modem's status page.

To log in to the modem, it requires certain username + password combination. Unlike all the samples that I have found, this comes before fetching the page, and therefore is not the case of finding the right id and then 'typing' the text into them.

Does Selenium have support for reaching such access controlled pages?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, if you use the following url, it will work:
`http://username:password@modemstatusurl/bar/foo`